# Can we lock file or folder in ubuntu by using open CV and C

Tags: c, opencv, ubuntu

I want to create a project to lock file and folders in ubuntu by face detection through opencv using C language. Can you please let me know it is possible and how can i do it.

Comment: using c is an unlucky choice with opencv. if you can't use c++, you will have to look out for another library (e.g. ccv)

Comment: latest opencv does not support face-detection from the c-api any more (using the stock cascade-files).

Comment: also, please clarify, if you meant *face-detection* (face or football?) or *face-recognition* (who is it?)

Answer (score 1):

Can't help you with the opencv part, but "lock file and folders" could mean a few things:

- You want to change permissions of files so that a given user/group can/cannot
  access them.  If this is the case, you want the `chmod` function. 
  See `man 2 chmod`.  Seems like this is probably what you're after?
- Usually, "file locking" on Linux refers to a means to prevent other processes from accessing a file without changing permissions via either:

  - Mandatory file locking via `lockf` (or `fcntl`).
  - Advisory file locking via `flock`.

If file locking is what you're after, here are the "see also" documents referred to by the man pages on `lockf` and/or `flock`:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/locks.txt

Note: Others have indicated you might want to use the `C++` API for `opencv`.  All of these functions should work just fine from C++ too.